# Rutas amigables con htaccess Not Found

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

Trato de crear rutas amigables en un sitio Web, utilizando una configuración en un archivo `htaccess`.

Estoy utilizando los servicios binarios de `Apache` y `PHP`, sin embargo al tratar de navegar por las páginas de mi sitio siempre me ha de mostrar `404 Not Found` dando a entender que no ha encontrado la rura buscada. Sin embargo ya he comprobado y las rutas esta bien. Lo que me ha llevado a pensar que tal vez no se esta leyendo o cargando en el servidor el archivo `htaccess`.

No se si habrá que configurar algo en el servidor para que se logre leer el archivo.

Agradecería si alguien puede orientarme en esta situación.

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución es de las más sencillas, para realizar rutas amigables para tu página web.

```
#Activar RewriteEngine para URL's amigables
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

El primer "regex" es para declarar variables, en este caso `$1` para introducir un GET en la URL. Puedes cambiar las páginas a las que hace referencia el regex, en mi caso estoy redireccionando a index.php pero podría ser a contacto.php.

En este enlace puedes encontrar algo más de información para reglas de rutas amigables: https://www.ionos.es/ayuda/hosting/htaccess/consejos-para-crear-reglas-de-reescritura-rewrite-rules/

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro, mi problema es que el servidor no parece cargar el archivo y convertir la ruta amigable en la ruta original.

Comment: @AdanEscobar tienes la página web en otro directorio dentro de la raíz? Algo tipo /pagina_web